# Eclipse Kepler won't start - Java error message

Tags: java, eclipse, kepler

I have downloaded Eclipse Kepler on my work laptop, & have confirmed my Windows system is 64 compatible. I also have Java 13 installed. When I go to start Eclipse for the first time, I get the following message: Failed to load the JNI shared library "C:Program Files\Java\jdk-13.0.1\bin\server\jvm.dll".

Here's what I've noted so far:
Java is installed on my machine under program files\java, but I noted there are 3 folders in there:
jdk1.8.0_161
jdk-13.0.1
jre1.8.0_121

I did update systems variables to point directly to the jdk-13.0.1 folder.
Eclipse is in its own folder obviously, but not sure if I need to move anything around, or if having 2 JDK folders like that is causing an issue. I'd try to uninstall Java, but this is a work machine so I'd need to wait for our Tech support department to open up tomorrow. I've contacted them twice & haven't been able to solve this & I'm getting desperate. Any tips?

Comment: `Kepler` was released in 2013, not sure if it will run smoothly with Java 13 (modules, ...)... (from its home page: *"Kepler is a past version of Eclipse. Please visit our download page for the latest version of Eclipse."*)

Comment: Why are you running an ancient version of Eclipse? Kepler will not run with Java 13, you need to use the current Eclipse 2021-03 for that.

Answer (score 0):

Inside eclipse folder open the file eclipse.ini in notepad or notepad++ you can find required java version mentioned like

```
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
```

and add the following in the last. Before this, you have to close Eclipse (you can add your preferred jdk version).

```
-vm C:\Java\JDK\1.8.0\bin\javaw.exe
```

After making changes, you can start eclipse. For more details, refer this link. https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini

Comment: Note: there must be a line break after `-vm`, that is, the path on a second line (and if I am not wrong, both lines must come just before `-vmargs`)